# Why invoke open() in libachk.so instead of in libc.so?

Tags: c, linux

I have a very strange SEGMENT FAULT stack as follow.

```
#0  0x00007f3b85fb0f6e in __strstr_sse42 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3b889b5415 in syscheckGetFdPath () from /lib64/libachk.so
#2  0x00007f3b889b4fc7 in acc_achkon_open () from /lib64/libachk.so
#3  0x00007f3b889b46d4 in open () from /lib64/libachk.so
#4  0x0000000000414d44 in nas_log_write_through(buff, size)
```

The source code of `nas_log_write_through()` function like this

```
void nas_log_write_through(char *buf, int size)
{
    int fd = 0;
    mode_t mod = umask(0);
    fd = open(LOG_PATH, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);
    umask(mod);    
    if (-1 == fd)
    {
        return;
    }

    write(fd, buf, size);
    close(fd);
}
```

In most case, it works well, but it suddenly works bad. and get core dump stack like previous shows. I want what is libachk.so doing? why syscall open() in libachk.so, instead of libc.so?

I have searched in Google, but got nothing useful. Any suggest is welcome.
Thanks a lot.

My system is SUSE 11 Linux, spc 1.

Comment: It's most likely that your `/etc/ld.so.preload` file has an entry for this library. And it sounds like the preload library has a bug in this case.

Comment: libachk seems to be some SUSE specific security library that intercepts calls to the libc and checks any provided argument before passing it on. And it seems to crash when checking if your LOG_PATH contains a certain string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. you mean that every or most syscalls, like open(), read(),write(), was intercepted by libachk,  and in libachk, it do some check, and then calls libc function finally? By the way, LOG_PATH contains very normal string "/var/log/naslog", it seems could not to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Petesh, it seems like what you say. But what strange is that, when I install this program on other machine, which system is the same as SUSE 11 spc1 linux,  It goes well. The content of /etc/ld.so.preload of two machine is the same string "libachk.so", and the output of cmd "ldd exe-program" in two machine is same, expect the address of lib.